# Behavior of if versus while in a recursive C++ function

Tags: c++, if-statement, recursion, while-loop, null

I'm new to C++, but I bumped into this problem on HackerRank and ran into a situation that seemed strange to me (coming from R/Python/Java):
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/tree-preorder-traversal

To give some background, the HackerRank problem was:

*Complete the preOrder function in your editor below, which has 1 parameter: a pointer to the root of a binary tree. It must print the values in the tree's preorder traversal as a single line of space-separated values.*

***Input Format:***
Our hidden tester code passes the root node of a binary tree to your preOrder function.

> Input:
>   6
>
> 3 5 2 1 4 6
>
> Expected Output:
>
> 3 5 1 4 2 6

I wrote this solution, which I thought would work:

```
//node is defined as:
/*
struct node
{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};
*/


void preOrder(node *root){
    while (root != NULL){ 
        cout << root->data << " ";
        preOrder(root->left);
        preOrder(root->right);
    }
    return;
}
```

This code, though, never terminates and instead outputs:

> 3 5 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1... (etc.)

What is strange and I am curious about is that if I change the `while` loop to the `if` conditional (as below) the program executes perfectly:

```
void preOrder(node *root){
    if (root == NULL){ 
        return;
    }
    cout << root->data << " ";
    preOrder(root->left);
    preOrder(root->right);
}
```

It is my understanding that both `if` and `while` ought to assess the condition each time `preOrder()` is called, but at some point, particularly after the 3rd iteration, the `preOrder()` function begins to continuously print 1 without terminating.

Any ideas, or could it be related to the `main()` code which I cannot see?

Comment: `while (root != NULL)` .. When this condition is satisfied, what is it that will make the loop stop?

Comment: shouldn't it call preorder(root->left) preorder(root->right) and be re evaluated with the new root-> data?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Each *invocation* of the function will work on its own `copy` it received for the pointer `root` as its parameter. Also, any *local variables* defined in the function are local to the invocation.

Comment: I see. Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`root` can never become null within the context of the final call to `preOrder`.

A common mistake with recursion is to confuse variables with the same name at different levels of the stack.  `root` from the first call to `preOrder` is *not* the same as `root` from the second call; rather, `root` from the second call is actually `root->left` or `root->right` from the first call.  But as the recursion is unwinding, if you ever make it back out to the original call to `preOrder`, then you will once again be dealing with the original `root`.

When you hit a leaf node, you call `preOrder` with `left` and `right` which will both immediately return because the while loop will fail.  Now you are back in the previous call to `preorder`, and `root` still points to the leaf node, not null.  Within this context, `root` never changes, therefore how could it ever make it out of the while loop?

Comment: Thanks so much for the very detailed answer-- I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2):

First of all,you have to see how preorder works  you are using

while

than calling

preOrder(root->left);

preOrder(root->right);

### but you have to store node's child  in stack before calling next nodes otherwise all nodes are not not reached

// An iterative process to print preorder traversal of Binary tree

`void iterativePreorder(node *root)`
`{`

```
`// Base Case`
`if (root == NULL)`
   `return;`

`// Create an empty stack and push root to it`
`stack<node *> nodeStack;`
`nodeStack.push(root);`
```

`/* Pop all items one by one. Do following for every popped item`

```
   `a) print it`

   `b) push its right child`

   `c) push its left child`
```

`Note that right child is pushed first so that left is processed first` `*/`

`while (nodeStack.empty() == false)`
    {

```
    `// Pop the top item from stack and print it`

   ` struct node *node = nodeStack.top();`

   ` printf ("%d ", node->data);`

   ` nodeStack.pop();`

    `// Push right and left children of the popped node to stack`
   ` if (node->right)`
       ` nodeStack.push(node->right);`
    `if (node->left)`
       ` nodeStack.push(node->left);`
```

`}`

`}`

here stack is used to store nodes